# What does blocking performance mean in RF transceivers' datasheet?

Tags: rf, wireless, transceiver

I have encountered two terms, *adjacent channel selectivity* (ACS) and *blocking performance* (BP), in TI cc1120's datasheet (http://www.ti.com/product/cc1120).

I found the definition of the former (ACS) here: http://www.telecomabc.com/a/acs.html.

> Adjacent Channel Selectivity (ACS) is a measure of a receiver’s ability to receive a signal at its assigned channel frequency in the presence of a strong signal in the adjacent channel.

However, I cannot find definition of the latter, i.e. BP (blocking performance).

Could anyone explain it in simple words? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at: http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slap127/slap127.pdf

In Slide 37, Adjacent Channel Selectivity, measured in dB, is the power difference between unwanted signal (in the adjacent channel) and the wanted signal to have a given link quality (Bit Error Rate in digital modulations). The wanted signal is set at sensitivity power level + 3 dB.

In Slide 40, Blocking (or desensitisation) is measured the same way as ACS but the interferer is not placed in adjacent channels but far away; in this case the interferer is usually not modulated (i.e. a pure sine).

Answer (score 1):

Blocking is the degree to which the sensitivity is reduced by the presence of high-power signals adjacent to the band of interest.

A quick googling found [this](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/receiver-overload/blocking.php), and [this](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/receiver-blocking):

> Blocking is defined as the degradation of receiver sensitivity, in the presence of a much stronger (blocking) signal.
>   Therefore we must first understand that Sensitivity is the measure of
>   what the smallest possible detectable signal is.
>
> Let's assume you have a radio receiver and you monitor a certain
>   signal at an SNR of 6 dB. Now if a much stronger signal was present
>   near your signal, the SNR of your desired signal would now be less
>   than 6 dB.
>
> Unfortunately for us, in all radio systems, the blocking signal does
>   not have to be masking the desired signal, as is commonly used in
>   electronic warfare. Blocking can also be caused by regular high power
>   radio signals spectrally near your desired signal.
>
> The simplest method for this kind of blocking to occur would be if the
>   interfering signal was strong enough causing the receiver LNA (the
>   first amplifier in the receiver) to reach its compression point, thus
>   causing a decrease in gain and potentially raising the amplifier's
>   noise figure.
>
> Due to this, "blocking dynamic range" is often defined as "the
>   difference in dB between the level of an incoming signal which will
>   cause 1 dB of gain compression, and the level of the noise floor".